# Close Dock and top bar

Tags: macos, applescript, dock, menu-bar

Is there a way to keep the application Dock closed. Every time I do:

```
killall dock
```

It closes for a bit then automatically reopens.
I want to be able to make an AppleScript program that keeps it closed. I remember I had to repeat `killall dock` again and again in a loop to keep it closed, but I find that stupid as the computer could lag which allowed dock to open for a split second.

I also want to hide/close the top bar, thus hiding the apple logo on the top left, but I could not find a way to do this. I could only hide the mini icons on the top right.

My essential task is to close finder, dock, the top bar and open a specific application of my choice, like a guest account, except that you can't turn off the computer. Can someone guide me to make such program? Specifically how to turn off the parts as mentioned (except for finder which is simply just `killall Finder`)?

Preferably, I want to be able to do this using Terminal or Applescript.

Comment: Best I've got is hiding the dock and the menu bar. To my understanding, OS X isn't designed to have either permanently closed, and doesn't really support this.

Comment: @JMY1000 Same. Wait you got dock to close without automatically reopening!?

Comment: No, just make it hidden until you mouseover. Same with menu bar.

Comment: On phone, so can't answer fully. Google 'kiosk mode mac' or 'simple finder Mac' & see if either of those would suit your needs.

Comment: @JMY1000 well people can still access the dock.

Comment: @Tetsujin found https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html but looks like I have to learn Objective-C with Xcode... I only know JavaScript, and AppleScript.

Comment: @Bradman175 Perhaps stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @JMY1000 well my originally intention was for AppleScript but if I have to use Xcode, I may have to resort to stackoverflow.com

Comment: @JMY1000 What will happen if i move the Dock app to another directory and restart the computer?

Comment: @Bradman175 No idea.

Comment: "My essential task is to close finder, dock, the top bar and open a specific application of my choice, like a guest account, except that you can't turn off the computer. “ If you want a UI that acts as a terminal console, boot up in Single User Mode.

Comment: Why not just use Parental Controls on a standard user? What do you really want to prevent access to that the Parental Controls solution doesn't limit?

Comment: @njboot Does that mean I can open an application of my choice and permanently disable the console so that the only way to reopen it is by restarting the computer through the physical power button?

Comment: I don't actually have a solution to this, but I was trying to resolve something similar yesterday. I was under the impression that one may get rid of the dock, but that the menu bar is something which will be difficult to go beyond hiding, as Apple very much wants it to be available, given all the functionalities in it, such as Force Quit, etc. An infinite loop may thus actually be your only choice, unless you can settle for a hiding option.

Comment: @nataliaeire I could try an overlay, but no idea how to insert an application on top of the overlay (like a fullscreen app that you can't quit). Another problem would be that if the program crashes, the overlay disappears, which is problematic.